# MS-Access query to exclude matching rows under specific conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access

Let's say that my company makes Sprockets and Widgets. There are 2 distinct types of each.

**Table A**

```
Product          ProductLine
Widget1          Widget
Widget2          Widget
Sprocket1        Sprocket
Sprocket2        Sprocket
```

Lets also say that there are 5 total parts that go into assembling the widgets and sprockets.

**Table B**

```
Part      Product
PartA     Widget1
PartB     Widget2
PartC     Sprocket1
PartD     Sprocket2
PartE     Widget1
partE     Widget2
partE     Sprocket1
PartE     Sprocket2
```

The company president decides to halt production of all Sprockets. What MS-Access query would work to return the list of all parts used only in the production of Sprockets?

```
SELECT Part
FROM B
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT *
 FROM A
 WHERE A.Product = B.Product
 AND A.ProductLine = "Widget")
```

This returns all the parts not used in the production of the Widgets line, i.e. all the parts used by Sprockets. But it includes PartE which is used in the Widget line as well.

SQl isn't my strong suit. I realize the NOT EXISTS/Widget and EXISTS/Sprocket will give the same result set. My problem is trying to filter out parts that are used for both Widgets and Sprockets. In reality, there are more than 2 ProductLines, so using something along the lines of COUNT() = 1 isn't very helpful.

This isn't a homework assignment. My company makes neither Widgets nor Sprockets, but the analogy is 100% dead on. :)

Thanks.

Comment: Is there an error in your sql example? part is not a column of table a.

Comment: Yep, had the tables backword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query goes direct to the product line and requests all parts that are not used in a widget production.

```
select part from tableb 
where part not in (select part from tableb 
                      inner join tablea on tableb.product=tablea.product
                   where tablea.productline='Widget')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/770e7/2

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only needing a list of parts, I tried to simplify it a bit.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT PART FROM B WHERE PRODUCT LIKE '*SPROCKET*' and PART NOT IN (SELECT PART FROM B WHERE PRODUCT LIKE '*WIDGET*')
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks good so far. In the actual table, there are over 1000 "parts", 120+ "products", and about a dozen "productlines". It isn't quick, but I don't need quick.